# unable to define relationship in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have two table as `sbj_topics` and `difficulty_level_sbj_topic` so, I want to define relationship  b\w them to fetch records, so to make relationship I have done this,

**SbjTopic.php:**

```
public function difficulty_level_sbj_topic() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\DiffiLvlSbjTopic');
}
```

And in **DiffiLvlSbjTopic.php:**

```
protected $table = 'difficulty_level_sbj_topic';
public function sbj_topics() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SbjTopic');
}
```

After that I returned the data to a view as:

```
$easy = DiffiLvlSbjTopic::where(['subject_id' => $id, 'difficulty_level_id' => 2])->get();
return view('diffi_lvls.show', compact('easy'));
```

Then in the **view** I done this:

```
@foreach($easy as $easy)
    {{ $easy->sbj_topics }}
@endforeach
```

but the page is blank, and when I do this `{{ $easy->sbj_topics->sbj_topic_name }}` **trying to get property of undefined!** comes.

The main purpose of creating relationship is to display **Subject Topic Name** because I have *foreign key* as `sbj_topic_id` in `difficulty_level_sbj_topic` table so if anyone has any other idea to do this without relationship that will be awesome.

Comment: Is this returning a collection? `dd($easy)`

Comment: yeah it's returning, but not the relationship values

Comment: `sbj_topic_id` is your FK right? Then what is `subject_id`? `$easy = DiffiLvlSbjTopic::where(['subject_id' => $id, 'difficulty_level_id' => 2])->get();`

Comment: I have a that's an other field in `difficulty_level_sbj_topic` table.

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper A subject has many difficulty levels or a difficulty level has many subjects? Look at the order of your relationships. Also, mention foreign keys explicitly so that Laravel doesn't assume anything by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break this down:

- SbjTopic - has many difflevels
- a difflevel belongs to aSbjTopic

With this understanding, I can see you are getting the difflevels (DiffiLvlSbjTopic). This is actually what you are passing to your blade.

So first off: complete your relationship by specify the foreign keys. i.e: 
In the SbjTopics model:

```
public function difficulty_level_sbj_topic() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\DiffiLvlSbjTopic', 'subject_id');
}
```

with this, you know that in the 'difficulty_level_sbj_topic' you must have the column `subject_id`. 
Now define the reverse relationship in your DiffiLvlSbjTopic model:

```
public function sbj_topics() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SbjTopic', 'subject_id');
}
```

With all these in place in your controller or route all you need to do is fetch the DiffiLvlSbjTopic model properties. For instance:

```
public function index () {
     $easy = DiffiLvlSbjTopic::all();
     return view('diffi_lvls.show', compact('easy'));
}
```

Finally in your view:

```
@foreach($easy as $difflevel)
    <div>{{ $difflevel->sbj_topics->name }} </div>
@endforeach
```

That's it.

Comment: OMG, that's great so I have only the mistake that I was not giving the foreign key in the reverse relationship.

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper Your bigger mistake is not following naming convention proposed in docs. By following, you'll avoid +90% this kind of unforced errors.

Comment: @Tpojka That is true, but specifying foreign keys to avoid magic is normally no bad thing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your both variables should not be `$easy` it can be something like `$easy as $easySingle`. And add a loop inside like

```
@foreach($easy as $easySingle)
    foreach ($easySingle->sbj_topics as $topic) {
      $topic->property;
    }   
@endforeach
```

Comment: **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** error coming

Comment: it's again empty bro I think there's a mess in relationship

Comment: again **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** error coming also did this `sbj_topics()`